# How to use NOT IN operator in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, notin

Write a query to display the movie number, movie title, and movie year for all movies that do not have a video. 
You will need to use a nested query approach. Use the results of the query that returns all the movie numbers from
the table VIDEO. This will be the sub-query. Apply the NOT IN operator to the results of the sub-query in the main query 
to then define the criteria.

```
select m.movie_num, m.movie_title, m.movie_year
from movie m, video v
where m.movie_num = v.movie_num;
```

Comment: Please use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists`:

```
select m.movie_num, m.movie_title, m.movie_year
from movie m
where not exists (select 1
                  from video v
                  where m.movie_num = v.movie_num
                 );
```

I strongly discourage the use of `not in` with a subquery.  It behaves strangely if *any* row in the subquery returns `NULL`.  In that case, *no rows at all are returned*.

You can express any `NOT IN` using `NOT EXISTS`.  And generally, you don't want a `NULL` value in the subquery to preclude all results.  Always use `NOT EXISTS`, and you won't have that problem.

Comment: You mean "Always use `NOT EXISTS`"?

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical use case for the `left join` antipattern:

```
select m.movie_num, m.movie_title, m.movie_year
from movie m
left join video v on  m.movie_num = v.movie_num
where v.movie_num is null
```

This phrases as: for each movie, try to locate the `video`(s) of each movie, and filter on movies for which no video exists.

This can also be expressed with a `not exists` condition:

```
select m.movie_num, m.movie_title, m.movie_year
from movie m
where not exists (select 1 from video v where m.movie_num = v.movie_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement that you must use `NOT IN` you can do this

```
select movie_num, movie_title, movie_year
from movie 
where movie_num not in (
  select movie_num
  from video
);
```

In this case it's safe to assume that there are no `NULL`s in the column `movie_num` in the table `video`.